# Calculating colour temperature from two sources of varying luminous intensity

Tags: color

I'd like to calculate the resultant colour temperature if I were to mix two different temperatures, each at a different intensity in lumens.

I have series of LEDs in two different temperatures, and would like to adjust the combined output using the two sources, but I can't find any information on this. Is it as simple as finding the mean, scaling for a higher luminosity in one source? I'm assuming that the latter portion won't be a simple linear relationship due to human perception.

Comment: Addition is of course wrong. Proof: place two identical light sources of 3000K temperatures side by side; the resultant is obviously 3000K and not 6000K.

Comment: Point taken, I meant to say the mean, but scaled according to the luminosity. I'll edit the question, thanks.

Comment: ok thats better. Now a calculation requires to know the spectrum of each sources. Their resultant will be a complex function though, depending on the exact shapes and overlap of those spectrums. I guess you cannot measure it, that's why you ask for computing it ?

Comment: Yes, the best source I have for information is the device's datasheet (https://download.luminus.com/datasheets/Luminus_CCT_Tunable_White_COB_LED_Module_Datasheet.pdf), where I am using the CTM-14-4018. Unfortunately I have no suitable measuring equipment.

Comment: yes the datasheet puts some information on the color CIE specifications. Not sure if that's sufficient to compute the color temperature of the mixture, but as a first approximation, your approach of flux-weighted averaging seems plausable at least for close initial color temperatures. For a more accurate approach I think some more color science expertice is required.

Comment: @Fat32 According to my calculations, flux-weighted averaging can give results that are off by at most 290 K.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo your computations seem highly accurate as always ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LEDs do not emit [black-body (*Planckian*) radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) which has a specific spectrum, so instead of *color temperature* which concerns black-body radiators we have to resort to *[correlated color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature#Correlated_color_temperature)* (CCT). It is the temperature of a black body that emits light of a color that is perceptually closest to the color of light of the same brightness from, in this case, the LEDs. The [CIE 1960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1960_color_space) $(u,v)$ chromaticity space ignores brightness and is designed to be perceptually uniform. It is used to calculate correlated color temperature and is based on the [CIE 1931](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space) $(X, Y, Z)$ color space.

Your LED datasheet gives for the two LED types their nominal fluxes in lumens and also gives their CIE 1931 $(x, y)$ chromaticities. Flux in lumens is calculated from a light spectrum using the CIE 1924 photopic (normal color vision, not low-light) luminosity function which is identical to the CIE 1931 spectral efficiency for the $Y$ color component, by definition. So we can work with normalized $(X, Y, Z)$ color where $Y$ equals the flux in lumens. This normalization is compatible between LED types of different chromaticities. Knowing $Y$ and the chromaticity $(x, y)$, we can easily calculate the rest of the $(X, Y, Z)$ triplet describing a LED type's light color, using the CIE 1931 definitions of $x$ and $y$:

> $$x = \frac{X}{X+Y+Z},\quad y = \frac{Y}{X+Y+Z}\tag{1}$$

$$\Rightarrow\quad X = \frac{Y\,x}{y},\quad Z = \frac{(1 - x - y)\,Y}{y}.\tag{2}$$

The $(X, Y, Z)$ color space is a linear-intensity color space so the $(X, Y, Z)$ colors of the LEDs sum additively in additive mixing of their lights. The correlated color temperature is then calculated from the summed $(X, Y, Z)$ color by going back to $(x, y)$ using the above definitions and by converting to CIE 1960 $(u, v)$ by the definition of that chromaticity space in relation to CIE 1931 chromaticity:

> $$u = \frac{4x}{12y - 2x + 3},\quad v = \frac{6y}{12y - 2x + 3}.\tag{3}$$

These steps could also be combined to a single equation. What remains to do is to find the temperature of a black-body that gives $(u, v)$ coordinates ([*Planckian locus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus)) nearest to this point by straight-line distance. Krystek, M. (1985), [**An algorithm to calculate correlated colour temperature**](http://doi:10.1002/col.5080100109). *Color Res. Appl.*, 10: 38-40 recommends using a bisection search together with the following rational Chebyshev approximation valid for $1000 < T < 15000$ where $T$ is temperature in kelvins:

> $$\begin{eqnarray}u = \frac{0.860117757+1.54118254 \times 10^{-4}T + 1.28641212 \times 10^{-7} T^2}{1+8.42420235 \times 10^{-4}T + 7.08145163 \times 10^{-7}T^2},\\
> v=\frac{0.317398726+4.22806245 \times 10^{-5}T + 4.20481691 \times 10^{-8} T^2}{1-2.89741816 \times 10^{-5}T+1.61456053 \times 10^{-7}T^2}.\end{eqnarray}\tag{4}$$

The [Colour](https://www.colour-science.org/) package (install using `pip install colour-science`) for Python includes the Krystek 1985 method but I just found a bug in [their implementation](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/pull/298) in version 0.3.14 which [will be fixed in version 0.3.15](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/issues/529). They also have other similar methods in function [`uv_to_CCT`](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.7/colour.html#colour.uv_to_CCT) and in other related functions. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import colour

# Subscript 0 denotes 1800K LED, 1 denotes 4000K LED.
# LED chromaticity center point:
xy_0 = np.array([0.5656, 0.4136])
xy_1 = np.array([0.3860, 0.3870])
# LED nominal flux (lumens) at nominal forward current:
flux_0 = 825
flux_1 = 1370
# Mixing weight (lumens)
weight_0 = flux_0
weight_1 = flux_1

# Proportional XYZ color at flux of 1 lumen (setting Y = 1):
XYZ_0 = np.array([xy_0[0]/xy_0[1], 1, (1 - xy_0[0] - xy_0[1])/xy_0[1]])
XYZ_1 = np.array([xy_1[0]/xy_1[1], 1, (1 - xy_1[0] - xy_1[1])/xy_1[1]])

# Correlated color temperatures of the two LED types
cct_0 = colour.xy_to_CCT(colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_0), method='McCamy 1992')
cct_1 = colour.xy_to_CCT(colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_1), method='McCamy 1992')

# Correlated color temperature of a mixture of the two LED types each at nominal current
colour.xy_to_CCT(colour.XYZ_to_xy(weight_0*XYZ_0 + weight_1*XYZ_1), method='McCamy 1992')
```

The obtained correlated color temperatures of the two LED types are `1746` and `3934` kelvins, close to their nominal CCTs of 1800 K and 4000 K. At nominal forward current for each LED type, the CCT of the mixture is `2715` kelvins. So the script seems to be working as intended.

We can also get a color temperature curve as function of mixing ratio, and see that it is not exactly linear, although this depends on the definition of a mixing ratio. Continuing in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ccts = np.zeros(101)
for percent_1 in range(101):
    weight_0 = (100-percent_1)*flux_0/100
    weight_1 = percent_1*flux_1/100
    ccts[percent_1] = colour.xy_to_CCT(colour.XYZ_to_xy(weight_0*XYZ_0 + weight_1*XYZ_1), method='McCamy 1992')

plt.plot(range(101), ccts, "-", range(101), cct_0*(100 - np.arange(101))/100 + cct_1*np.arange(101)/100, "--")
plt.ylabel("correlated color temperature (K)")
plt.xlabel("4000 K LED flux / nominal flux (%)")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]
*Figure 1. Correlated color temperature (solid blue) of a mixture of 1800 K and 4000 K LED types at different mixing ratios. 0 % and 100 % mean a single LED type operating at its nominal flux at its nominal forward current and the other LED type off. 50 % means each LED type is operating at half of its nominal flux. Calculations use manufacturer's LED data. A linear relation (dashed orange) is shown for comparison.*

Comment: Very nice as always (+1). The critical point is the conversion algorithm from CIE 1960 (u,v) chromacity varibles to the associated correlated color temperature that's from the paper Krystek 1985. How justified is that? Did it become an established standard by the optical color science community... Sorry if I don't know much about that.

Comment: @Fat32 I don't know what the standard is exactly, would have to pay money. But the idea seems to be to use a theoretical physics black body radiation curve and the CIE 1931 spectral sensitivity curves for determining the color, and CIE 1960 uv to measure the color difference. Other than using some approximation, there doesn't seem to be any wiggle room. At worst Krystek's approximation could be off by a distance of about $10^{-4}$ in uv space. I think it would take about 10 times as much difference for a perceivable difference. So the approximation is good enough to replace the real thing.

Comment: Thank you very much Olli, a superb answer. It will take me some time to digest fully. :)

Comment: @Fat32 Then again there is also the newer CIE 1976 (u', v') perceptually uniform chromaticity space so some standards might have made the switch to that from CIE 1960 (u, v) for the definition of correlated color temperature.

Comment: @Fat32 The CIE 15:2004 technical report Colorimetry effectively recommends to calculate the correlated color temperature using the CIE 1960 (u, v) color space: The text talks of a diagram with axes (u', 2/3 v') which, with that factor 2/3, happens to be isotropically proportional to (u, v). That seems a way to be backwards compatible while using the new CIE 1976.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Ok Olli,  I'm convinced enough :-)). Very good answer of its own kind, but (why) not getting enough support from the community...

Comment: Good answer, a couple of comments about the code:
1. xy->XYZ conversion is already implemented (`colour.xy_to_XYZ`). No need to implement the formula.
2. The internal call to `colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ_[0/1])` is superfluous since xy chromacity is already known.

Answer (score 0):

The disappointing news, which I do know enough to give you, is that you can't get there from here.  Unfortunately, I couldn't tell you exactly how to get there without studying more myself.

The reason you can't get there from here is because hitting a color temperature requires setting *at least three* values in the correct ratios (if you just want to claim a color temperature vs. the typical human eye response), and just adding up two arbitrary light sources -- or even two light sources that are giving out "correct" black body radiation -- may not fit any color temperature curve.

As an extreme example (and about the only one I'm fit to give you), if you have a source at 1500K it will be mostly red.  Now turn on a source at 15000K -- the 15000K source is mostly blue.  If you scale the sources so they're putting out equal light, you'll get lots of red, lots of blue, and little green.  That doesn't fit *any* color temperature curve -- it's just weird purple light.

I'm almost ready to fall off the edge of my competence, but just to add to your woes, if you've got a red, a blue, and a green light, then part of the challenge of achieving a decent color curve is to take the human eye's color response into account -- and when you're done, some artist will tell you that you're not matching natural light, so the colors of some objects will still be off.

Comment: The datasheet linked to in the comments has enough information for doing the calculation.